# Unexpected behaviour exhibited by Python's JSON module

Tags: python, json, file, dictionary, contextmanager

I am doing a simple wrapper program around a software tool, and this wrapper will, among other things, parse a JSON configuration file that will be coded by the user as a way for the user to specify certain configutations to the program.

Within the program, I have the following lines of code:

```
with open(os.path.join(args.config_bin_dir, 'basic_config.json'), 'r') as jsondata :
    print "JSON File contents:", jsondata.read()
    basic_config.update(json.load(jsondata))
    print "The basic_config after updating with JSON:", basic_config
jsondata.close()
```

The *basic_config* object is a dictionary object that gets constructed somewhere on top earlier up in the program, and over here I want to add the new dictionary key-value pairs obtained from parsing the user's JSON configuration file into the *basic_config* dictionary object.

When the program is run, I get the following error, a section of which is as follows:

```
File "path/to/python/script.py", line 42, in main
    basic_config.update(json.load(jsondata))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 290, in load
  **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
  return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
  obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
  raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I'm quite puzzled by this error, but I noticed that it goes away so long as I remove the line `print "JSON File contents:", jsondata.read()` and run the code as either:

```
with open(os.path.join(args.config_bin_dir, 'basic_config.json'), 'r') as jsondata :
    # print "JSON File contents:", jsondata.read()
    basic_config.update(json.load(jsondata))
    print "The basic_config after updating with JSON:", basic_config
jsondata.close()
```

or

```
with open(os.path.join(args.config_bin_dir, 'basic_config.json'), 'r') as jsondata :
    # print "JSON File contents:", jsondata.read()
    basic_config.update(json.load(jsondata))
    # print "The basic_config after updating with JSON:", basic_config
jsondata.close()
```

I'll still get the same error if I comment out the line after the `json.load` method:

```
with open(os.path.join(args.config_bin_dir, 'basic_config.json'), 'r') as jsondata :
    print "JSON File contents:", jsondata.read()
    basic_config.update(json.load(jsondata))
    # print "The basic_config after updating with JSON:", basic_config
jsondata.close()
```

So I'm guessing that it has to do with calling the `read` method on the JSON file object before parsing that same file. Could anyone please explain to me why this is so, and whether I am mistaken about the cause of the error?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

When you call `read()` on a file handle, its current read position is advanced to the end of the file. This mirrors the behavior of the underlying file descriptors. You can reset to the start of a file via `jsondata.seek(0, 0)`.